# optimizar código Javascript-Jquery para que sea mas rápido y con mejores practicas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como podría mejorar este código, teniendo en cuenta el performance.

Siento que por tanto ciclo puede afectar, ya que es una web pesada tanto en backend como en frontend(estructura compleja, muchas paginas, peticiones, servicios), que me podrían recomendar?

```
function () {
var self = this;
for (var p = 0; p < this.countPaxes; p++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.countJourneys; j++) {
        var divs = this.jqueryWrapper.Find($(document), "div[data-type='segment'][data-journeynumber='" + j + "']");

        Enumerable.From(divs).ForEach(function (div, i) {

            var infoSection = $(div).parent();
            var liList = self.jqueryWrapper.Find(infoSection, "li[data-ssrcode]");

            Enumerable.From(liList).ForEach(function (li) {
                var ssrcode = self.jqueryWrapper.Attr(li, "data-ssrcode");
                var repeatedSsrCodes = self.jqueryWrapper.Find(infoSection, "li[data-ssrcode='" + ssrcode + "']");
                if (repeatedSsrCodes.length === 2) {
                    Enumerable.From(repeatedSsrCodes).ForEach(function (repeatedSsrCode) {
                        $(repeatedSsrCode).hide();
                    });
                }
            });


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: El título es demasiado general. Por favor pon algo más específico. Por otro lado, agrega más detalles, ¿qué es una web muy pesada? ¿te refieres al front-end o al back-end? Seguramente al front-end, pero ¿qué lo hace pesada? ¿tiene muchas páginas, una estructura muy compleja, muchos recursos?

Answer (score 1):

Una buena practica y el performance es no declarar variables ni funciones dentro de bucles por ejemplo cambiaria esto

```
for (var p = 0; p < this.countPaxes; p++) {
for (var j = 0; j < this.countJourneys; j++) {
```

por esto:

```
var p = 0;
var j = 0;
var cPages = this.countPaxes;
var cJourneys = this.countJourneys;
for ( p; p < cPages; p++ ) {
for ( j; j < cJourneys; j++ ) {
```

Comment: En ninguno de los ejemplos que colocas declara variables dentro de blucles, por lo que no mejoras el performance como mencionas.

Comment: Mas bien diría que el primer código que colocas es mejor, porque reduces el ámbito de la variable, una vez terminado el ciclo `for(var p = 0; p < this.countPaxes; p++)` la variable `p` desaparecerá.

Comment: Y como le llamas al hacer esto? for (var p = 0)
Cada vez que entras al ciclo for abres un espacio en memoria para crear una nueva variable p por n veces y le asignas el valor cero n veces, lo mismo para cuando usas length dentro del un for. aqui les dejo una fuente de tantas que hay en internet
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqf5qPFehBI">Ejemplo</a>

Comment: Ummm estás mal, cuando ejecutas `for(var p = 0; p < this.countPaxes; p++)` asignas el espacio en memoria de la variable `p` sólo una vez, no n veces y no le asigna el valor de `0` n veces. Funciona igual que si lo declararas de la segunda forma que colocas, por lo que no ganas en rendimiento y agrega complejidad al código visualmente. Si la variable estuviera así `for(...){ var p = 0; }` sería como tu dices.

Comment: Bueno, si esta mal no me molestare que editen mi respuesta, siempre es para mejorar.

Comment: @Jemonge ya veo lo que dices. Te entiendo mejor ahora :)